# Use the Linq Count

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to show  OrderDetails  Count near the orders information in the grid but in the select Unit i can only select the Key and Count. What is the way to select the orders information?

```
var Q = from Data in Context.Orders
        join D2 in Context.OrderDetails on Data.OrderID equals D2.OrderID
        group Data by Data.OrderID into grouped
                       select new
                              {
                                  grouped=g.Key,
                                  Count = grouped.Count() 
                              };
```

Comment: Select _what_ "orders information"?

Comment: I want to select all the orders information and then show the count of orderDetail in the last column in gridview

Comment: btw, don't you mean `grouped = grouped.Key`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group it by whole order entity like

```
var Q = from Data in Context.Orders
        join D2 in Context.OrderDetails on Data.OrderID equals D2.OrderID
        group Data by Data into grouped
                       select new
                              {
                                  OrderId = grouped.Key.OrderId,
                                  OrderDate = grouped.Key.OrderDate
                                  Shipping = grouped.Key.Shipping
                                  .
                                  .
                                  .
                                  Count = grouped.Count() 
                              };
```

**EDIT** Linqpad program for similar query on in memory collection of objects

```
void Main()
{
    var orders = new List<Order>{
        new Order{OrderId = 1, DeliverIn = 5},
        new Order{OrderId = 2, DeliverIn = 6},
        new Order{OrderId = 3, DeliverIn = 5},
    };

    var lines = new List<OrderLine>{
      new OrderLine{LineId = 1, OrderId = 1, ProductId = 1},
      new OrderLine{LineId = 2, OrderId = 1, ProductId = 2},
      new OrderLine{LineId = 3, OrderId = 1, ProductId = 3},

      new OrderLine{LineId = 4, OrderId = 2, ProductId = 1},
      new OrderLine{LineId = 5, OrderId = 2, ProductId = 3},
      new OrderLine{LineId = 6, OrderId = 2, ProductId = 4},
    };

    var query = from o in orders join l in lines on
            o.OrderId equals l.OrderId
            group o by o into grouped
            select new 
            {
                Count = grouped.Count(),
                grouped.Key.OrderId,
                grouped.Key.DeliverIn
            };
            Console.WriteLine(query);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Order
{
    public int OrderId{get;set;}
    public int DeliverIn{get;set;}

}

public class OrderLine
{
    public int LineId{get;set;}
    public int OrderId{get;set;}
    public int ProductId{get;set;}
}
```

and if you don't have linq pad simply go and grab it from [their site](http://www.linqpad.net/). It is simply awesome.

Comment: It should be working. I tested it against in memory collection of objects. let me update the answer to show that code.

Comment: thanks you for you answer it is correct and its working.is there a way to select ProductId from  OrderLine?

Comment: There are multiple product lines hence multiple ProductId's per order. How do you suppose to get one ProductId per Order

Comment: First decide what result you want from your query and maybe write it down. It will ease up things for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [IGrouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) documentation on MSDN.

```
public interface IGrouping<out TKey, out TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement>, 
IEnumerable
```

Pay attention to [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx). Count is just an extension method of IEnumerable. You can easily Select from grouping or loop through it.

For example:

```
var Q = from Data in Context.Orders
    join D2 in Context.OrderDetails on Data.OrderID equals D2.OrderID
    group Data by Data.OrderID into grouped
                   select new
                          {
                              grouped=g.Key,
                              Count = grouped.Count(),
                              Orders = grouped.ToArray() 
//you can also just return grouped itself to support lazy queries
                          };
```

Answer (score 0):

Just flatten them into array or list and then get its count.

```
select new
{
    Key = g.Key,
    Orders = grouped.ToArray()
};
```

Then get count:

```
int count = result.Orders.Count; // Property of an array.
```